# Recursive combination function - Error of subscript

Tags: recursion, fortran, fortran90

I am getting this error and can't debug my code, could u guys help me?The objective is to get the combination of N numbers in of m points each.

```
 program combinations

     implicit none
     integer, parameter :: m_max = 3
     integer, parameter :: n_max = 5
     integer, dimension (m_max) :: comb
     character (*), parameter :: fmt='(i0' // repeat(', 1x, i0', m_max - 1) // ')'

     call gen (1)

   contains

     recursive subroutine gen (m)

       implicit NONE
       integer, intent (in) :: m
       integer :: n

       if (m.gt.m_max) then
         write (*,fmt) comb
       else
         do n = 1, n_max
           if ((m.eq.1).OR.(n.gt.comb(m-1))) then
             comb(m)= n
             call gen (m + 1)
           end if
         end do
       end if

     end subroutine gen

   end program combinations
```

The error i'm getting is this: Subscript #1 of the array Comb has value 0 which is less than the lower bound of 1.

I don't understand this message, so please, help me

Answer (score 3):

The run-time message from the compiler is clear: you are attempting to access the element `comb(0)` when the lower bound of the array `comb` is 1 (and upper bound `m_max`).

This access happens in the first call to `gen` when `m` takes the value 1.  You have the access `n.gt.comb(m-1)`.  This is bad.

It seems that you think that there may be some short-circuiting as you first test `m.eq.1`.  If this is true, you may think, then the logical condition is already true and the `n.gt.comb(m-1)` isn't tested.  This is not the case.

Comment: Yeah, now i understand what the problem is. Can't I bypass this? Perhaps adding another "if" condition. Yeah, it worked. Thanks so much

Comment: Separating the `m.eq.1` case makes sense, but you could also have the lower bound of `comb` as 0 (`comb(0:m_max)`) with a sensible value (but later reference only `comb(1:)`.  Note also that in the first reference to `comb(0)` that value hasn't actually been defined.  Another reason to have `m.eq.1` as a special case.